# Traversal matrix in "circle"

Tags: arrays, algorithm, loops, matrix

I don’t know how to go through elements in array in special order. Input array look like this:
[image: input matrix]

And I need to go like this

[image: way to go]

Only way I came to, is some sort of brute force:

```
int Rings[][] = new int [3][12];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            Rings[i][0] = matrix[2-i][5];
            Rings[i][1] = matrix[2-i][4];
            Rings[i][2] = matrix[2-i][3];
            Rings[i][3] = matrix[3][2-i];
            Rings[i][4] = matrix[4][2-i];
            Rings[i][5] = matrix[5][2-i];
            Rings[i][6] = matrix[6+i][3];
            Rings[i][7] = matrix[6+i][4];
            Rings[i][8] = matrix[6+i][5];
            Rings[i][9] = matrix[5][6+i];
            Rings[i][10] = matrix[4][6+i];
            Rings[i][11] = matrix[3][6+i];
}
//Rings[0] = 9,6,3,7,8,9,1,4,7,3,2,1
//Rings[1] = 8,5,2,4,5,6,2,5,8,6,5,4
//Rings[2] = 7,4,1,1,2,3,3,6,9,9,8,7
```

It’s look not too bad if it 9x9 but if it will be bigger, even with 10x10 array “Rings” will be 16. Is it possible to go through matrix in circle style without touching corner elements? Clockwise or counterclockwise doesn’t matter, with what circle to begin, doesn’t matter either.

Comment: Please can you post the problem statement or give the link to it?

Comment: @amrender singh As i understand you want to know why i deside to ask this question and come up to this problem? i just fooling around with sudoku and methods for traversing matrixes zigzag/spiral etc, and ask myself is it possible to travers with "circles".

Comment: How would you define the corner matrices ? Are they always 3x3 ? In that case the minimum size of the matrix for this problem should be 9x9 right?

Comment: @SomeDude Whole input array is matrix, i define center and corner part of matrix with "-1" for simplicity of understanding. No they can be 4x4, 5x5 etc. And minimum size may be 1x1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that each of the 4 sides of every ring has an invariant index, and convert into 4 for-loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
   int j = 0;
   for (int k = 5; k > 2; k--)
      Rings[i][j++] = matrix[2-i][k];
   for (int k = 3; k < 6; k++)
      Rings[i][j++] = matrix[k][2-i];
   for (int k = 3; k < 6; k++)
      Rings[i][j++] = matrix[6+i][k];
   for (int k = 5; k > 2; k--)
      Rings[i][j++] = matrix[6+i][k];
}
```

Generalizing to grid size `N`:

- Replace the 2 in `2 - i` with `N - 1` (inner loop, left / top)
- Replace the 6 in `6 + i` with `2 * N` (inner loop, right / bottom)

Code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
   int j = 0;
   for (int k = 2 * N - 1; k >= N; k--)
      Rings[i][j++] = matrix[N - 1 - i][k];
   for (int k = N; k < 2 * N; k++)
      Rings[i][j++] = matrix[k][N - 1 - i];
   for (int k = N; k < 2 * N; k++)
      Rings[i][j++] = matrix[2 * N + i][k];
   for (int k = 2 * N - 1; k >= N; k--)
      Rings[i][j++] = matrix[2 * N + i][k];
}
```